# Return by reference is consistently faster than return value and stack with recursion

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, optimization

The below code consistently returns results around this: `time - passed: 30 returned: 141 stacked: 212 for: 31` with roughly the same order always, my interpretation is:

The returned by reference function is just as fast as the for loop function, is this because the scope doesn't have to be preserved, nor reallocated on every call.  It just uses the same memory while iterating the `depth`- just like the for loop?  And maybe it can be very slightly quicker because the function itself doesn't have to allocate the `result`.  While the returned function preserves the `depth` of every call before adding them all up once everything is called?  And maybe the stack function is the slowest because it has to constantly free and request again the same memory?

At higher max depths the `passed` is slower than `for` by a bit, and `returned` is slower than `stacked` by a bit.  But `passed`/`for` stay around at least 4x faster than `stacked`/`returned`

Are my guesses for the performance difference correct?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <vector>

const std::int32_t MAX_DEPTH = 20;
const int ITERATIONS = 100000000;
std::int32_t returned_calls = 0;
std::int32_t passed_calls = 0;
std::int32_t stacked_calls = 0;
std::int32_t for_calls = 0;

void passed_func(std::int32_t depth, std::int32_t& result) {
    passed_calls++;
    depth += 1;
    result += depth;
    if (depth == MAX_DEPTH) {
        return;
    }
    passed_func(depth, result);
}

std::int32_t returned_func(std::int32_t depth) {
    returned_calls++;
    depth += 1;
    if (depth == MAX_DEPTH) {
        return depth;
    }
    return returned_func(depth) + depth;
}

std::int32_t stacked_func() {
    std::int32_t result = 0;
    std::vector<std::int32_t> stack;
    stack.emplace_back(1);
    while (true) {
        stacked_calls++;
        std::int32_t depth = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        result += depth;
        if (depth == MAX_DEPTH) {
            return result;
        }
        stack.emplace_back(depth + 1);
    }
}

std::int32_t for_func() {
    std::int32_t result = 0;
    for (std::int32_t depth = 1; depth <= MAX_DEPTH; depth++) {
        for_calls++;
        result += depth;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::uint64_t passed_time = 0;
    std::uint64_t returned_time = 0;
    std::uint64_t stacked_time = 0;
    std::uint64_t for_time = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        std::int32_t passed_result = 0;
        std::int32_t returned_result = 0;
        std::int32_t stacked_result = 0;
        std::int32_t for_result = 0;
        std::uint64_t t1 = __rdtsc();
        passed_func(0, passed_result);
        std::uint64_t t2 = __rdtsc();
        returned_result = returned_func(0);
        std::uint64_t t3 = __rdtsc();
        stacked_result = stacked_func();
        std::uint64_t t4 = __rdtsc();
        for_result = for_func();
        std::uint64_t t5 = __rdtsc();
        if (passed_result != returned_result || stacked_result != returned_result || for_result != returned_result) {
            return 1;
        }
        passed_time += t2 - t1;
        returned_time += t3 - t2;
        stacked_time += t4 - t3;
        for_time += t5 - t4;
    }
    if (returned_calls != passed_calls || stacked_calls != returned_calls || for_calls != returned_calls) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout
        << "time - passed: " << passed_time / ITERATIONS
        << " returned: " << returned_time / ITERATIONS
        << " stacked: " << stacked_time / ITERATIONS
        << " for: " << for_time / ITERATIONS
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First question before you draw any conclusions: What build flags did you use?

Comment: @tadman default MSVC Release config

Comment: @Aidan which optimization level flags?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ default so: `Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)`

Comment: Looks like passed is a perfect tail-call form, whereas returned is a little harder for the optimizer. What happens if you change it to `return depth + returned_func(depth);` ?

Comment: @Useless I thought that might have an effect, but no its the same.

Comment: OK, so your next step is to try using a proper profiling tool and/or look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @Useless Yes, but also what's the point of asking any optimization question on here then?  I asked because I was hoping experts in the topic may know because this is a very common type of thing to implement.  Rather than having to dedicate the hours to learning a profiling tool and/or to be able to read asm.  Any question that can be answered by another person could be answered by yourself with enough studying, but that isn't a efficient use of time compared to just asking someone who's already an expert.  This feels like telling someone asking how to change a timing belt to study the diagram.

Comment: Yep, software is hard, performance is contingent, and you already ruled out the only obvious well-kown effect: tail-call optimization. What's left is hoping someone saw exactly the same thing with exactly the same compiler and options, hoping someone else reads the assembly for you, and reading the assembly yourself.

Comment: @Useless I can't test myself right now, but I image the optimization across compilers for this basic of functionality is the same.  And this problem will be encountered by essentially every programmer implementing any kind of recursive logic.  So, yeah, I think it is fair to hope for the first.  Again, aren't all questions essentially just "hoping someone saw exactly the same thing" or at least "hoping someone saw something similar enough to extrapolate the same thing"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256029/discussion-between-useless-and-aidan).

Comment: gcc [simply computes the result of the recursive function at compile time](https://www.godbolt.org/z/Gaq6T3zTb), as does clang. Btw, I assume that the vector allocation dominates the runtime in the stacked func. Dynamic allocation is expensive.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That isn't done when you simply remove the static function definition you added.  I'm not wanting to optimize for a constant answer, I could just hard code that.  I am wanting to understand the optimization of recursive functions with a simple example.

Comment: @Aidan The compiler emits code for the function (because somebody might link to it) but still computes the result at compile time (line 84 [without static](https://www.godbolt.org/z/jr6xKrsvn)). I just wanted to caution you regarding the interpretation of benchmark results. I can imagine that using a vector to buffer the value "blinds" the compiler, so it cannot optimize the calls, even though it is clear to us that it is the same logic and the vector calls have no relevance and could be optimized away under the "as if" rule.

Comment: (I suppose the compiler cannot assume -- rightly! -- that the vector allocation and access functions are side-effect free.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Oh I see!! That makes sense, I will try to with dynamically passed args in the future, or some other trick to stop premature optimization.

Comment: @Useless the replacement return depth + returned_func(depth); does not make the function tail recursive. The last action of the function is still the call to  int32_t operator+(const int_32&,const int_32&) Operator. Nevertheless, that was what I tried first, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intressing observation. I was able to reproduce your result approximatly on my maschine.

```
time - passed: 30 returned: 83 stacked: 197 for: 30
```

One observation i made was that stacked may be accerelated if one delclares
`std::vector<std::int32_t> stack;`
as global variable and replace the definiton of the vecor in the function body by
`stack.clear()`
This avoids 99.999 heap allocations. After that replacement i got on my machine

```
time - passed: 29 returned: 84 stacked: 77 for: 30
```

But that's just by the way.

I would say your summary is totally correct, but it have little to do wether you use return by value or by reference. What you describe is called tail call optimization. If a recursive function call is the last action of the function and after the call returns the calling function have nothing to do then return its result, the compiler can replace the recursive call  by a simple jump to the functions begin, i.e. its behave almost like the for loop.
With a small modification one can make also the `returned_func` version tail recursive:

```cpp
std::int32_t returned_func(std::int32_t depth,std::int32_t accumulator=0) {
    returned_calls++;
    depth += 1;
    accumulator += depth;
    if (depth == MAX_DEPTH) {
        return accumulator;
    }
    return returned_func(depth,accumulator);
}
```

and voila, the returned_func version is almost as fast as the for version:

```
time - passed: 29 returned: 36 stacked: 80 for: 31
```

But so far all what i sayed is a educated guess. If we want to know it exactly, we have to look at the resulting assembler code. Here is a comparison of the your "returned" variant with the "passed" variant in the compiler explorer, using msvc19.latest /O2.
https://godbolt.org/z/9avEK6soq
we see in the "passed" version there is no recursive function call, its just replaced by a conditional jump: 'jne     SHORT $LL9@passed_fun'  while in the return version we have the recursive call
'call    int returned_func(int)'

With the modified `returned_func`
https://godbolt.org/z/Mn9P4Yhbc
both version result in very similar assembly code.

edit: i wrote so long on my answer that i missed the ALX23z's answer, which came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for investigating, and the idea of an accumulator!  I hadn't thought of a way to actually optimize the returned function but that is a good idea and might actually be applicable in my use case!

Comment: @Aidon Oh, I just slightly modified the idea from the standard example of how to make the recursive function for calculating the factorial tail recursive,

Answer (score 2):

The situation you expirience is a fairly common optimization. The `passed_function` is optimized into a for-loop instead of the recursive call. The optimization is possible because body of the function has completed the execution by the time it needs to perform the recursive call.

In `returned_func` the optimization doesn't happen as it still needs to compute `... + depth;` after the recursive call.

Comment: Thank you!  Does the optimized passed function get unwrapped at all?  Also, will this happen with any recursive `void` passed function?(where the recursion is at the end of the logic)  And, why is the for loop so much faster than the `stacked`?  Is it from all the allocations?

Comment: Stacked is definitely expensive because of the allocations, yes. That's the most expensive thing by far in all your code. But you already ruled out enabling the tail-call optimization in returned (although the only way to be sure is to check the assembly)

Comment: @Aidan in `stacked` you have dynamic memory manipulations. They tend to be slower than operations on the stack. As I said, the optimization has nothing to do with return type, be it `void`, `int`, or something else. It is due the function completing everything else prior to the recursive call.

Comment: _In returned_func the optimization doesn't happen as it still needs to compute ... + depth; after the recursive call._ -- It's not impossible, that's just MSVC. Clang transforms that recursion into a loop https://godbolt.org/z/z6ofzhs39

Comment: @chrysante ofcourse it isn't impossible. It's just a newer and smarter optimization while the one I referred to is rather archaic and existed for over 20 years.

Comment: @chrysante I incremented the optimisation to -O2 at your ce link... i am really impressed, clang removes then the complete loop, it realises that you sum up 1..depht, returnes (deph-1)*deph/2 and adds depth to call counter.

Comment: @WhoAmI it is always bizzare what compilers able to optimize and yet fail at other times. Like a case where a linked list's usage is optimized out completely in some trivial function but fails if it were replaced with a vector.